# It's about how to create automatic html files and fill it or copy it with small change

Tags: php, html, database

i'am now designing a shopping website and i done the design alright ? , but i face a problem , when the user open the product it will take him to link right? i'm php coder but should i manually create for each product file on the root or query name ?, look at this example 
http://zubaidaljarmy.site88.net/GeoxProject/web/single.html
, i want for each product to be like this page but with small change , can i do it automatic ? or should i manually create for each product ? and thanks

Comment: Please instead of putting link, kindly put the code you have tried.

Comment: actually i didn't have the idea to create a code that's why i asked i mean i know mkdir php code for creating folders but its not make any since, ok im php coder but don't have the idea how ti do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, every product must be inserted to DB (name, desc, images, etc..), after that you can make an HTML page that looks however you want to look like. Then you select the appropriate data of specific product from DB and show it on that HTML page.

Comment: i got this bro but i will give this example , when u create your stackoverflow account , and then you open your profile link, you will get something like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4832775/firas-rassas), how can i do that , that create folders with product name or product number and fill it with the data ,

Comment: every link like this: "http://stackoverflow.com/users/" + id + name going to select that user data and set it into HTML profile page

Comment: okay i'm with you and i know how to do that , but when i create folder how can i fill it with html codes? i mean , look at your link "http://stackoverflow.com/users/4832775/firas-rassas" , inside firas-rassas folder there is index.php file right? how did they do that page and fill it with data , i know how to fill it with data but how to write code inside of it (automatically ). or copy the php file into your folder

Comment: no there is no folder with firas-rassas name neither 4832775 name, they're just a parameters on the link, so they can select that user's data from DB

Comment: you can make it in a different way, like
http://yoursite.com/index.php?id=483&name=zubaid or 
http://yoursite.com/index.php/483/zubaid
you determine how the link will be look like

Comment: ahaaaaaaaa , so can u tell me bro firas how to change it like this? i mean the parameters on the link ? and thank you for helping

Comment: ahaaa i got this brooo , yy i got this , so in every product in the <link href="" , in the href i will give it name and id manually right? ,for each product

Comment: Yes, look at this link. It shows how you can read parameters from URL with forward slashes.
http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-general/0159ts8x8h/passing-parameters-in-the-url-using-forward-slashes

Comment: <link href="yoursite.com/product/id/name"> 
id, name variables you shoud get them from DB.. you dont write the id and the name of any product manually.
make a select query from database get name and id then put them into that link, by javascript or jquery..